# My Tensorflow lite model accuracy and Image Classification issues

Tags: android-studio, image-processing, deep-learning, tensorflow-lite

First off, I've succeed in deploying my fine tuned Xception model to my android application, it working fine, except some harsh image that it predicted wrong, however, on my computer, with that image, it's predicted correct even though the accuracy was around 50-60%. So, is converting to tensorflow lite model reduce my model accuracy a little bit.
Secondly, my biggest question, if we have 4 label predicting model, what if we input another object that is not in the 4 label declared. I'm trying to solve this by increasing my object detected to around 1000 objects :) but it so difficult when also trying to adding my object (which is 1004 objects). Any solution that could clarify whether the object is in the label or not? Thank for solve my issue.
the last issue which is derived from the second issue :(, are there anyway to adding label from an already-created model ? For example Xception with 1000 objects could be detected in default, now I want to add 4 or more extra object to the model, how could I do it? I've flicked through sites, they all said that we need to train our model again :( but 1004 objects is to computational expensive.
Thankyou for solving my problem, appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Conversion to TensorFlow Lite *is* expected to reduce accuracy, especially for outlier inputs such as the one you describe.

If you provide an input from a class that the model was not trained on, the output is 'undefined' - the logits will essentially be garbage.

If you want a model that has more labels than the one you have, you will need to retrain :-)

Comment: The second statement seems to be unclear, I mean, for example I got 10 labels, so even I input in the model undefined image, it will still land on some of the label out of 10 :(